# Mouse infestation cleanup advice

Tags: insulation, cleaning, interior

We had/have a bad mouse infestation. It appears they setup shop in the attic, but then moved into the interior of our home :(.

Example attic:
[image: attic]

Example interior (under stove, eating the couch!, basement floor)
[image: inside]

Finished basement (drop ceiling, insulation shots)
[image: basement]

We've set snap traps throughout the house and poison in the attic - we haven't seen fresh signs in about 2 weeks. We've deep cleaned the interior of the home with bleach, and had professional carpet and upholstery cleaners come out. We've gone through absolutely everything in the house looking for any signs, and cleaned out everything. I've gone through the exterior of the home and put in copper mesh in any openings.

My question... what "should I do" about the hard to clean areas (e.g. attic, basement drop ceiling, contaminated insulation, etc.)?

In your opinion should I have professional cleaners come in? I feel like if I contact a professional wildlife cleanup service they will tell me that it needs to be cleaned up, because that's how they get paid. In my eyes this whole mess looks horrible, and I feel like everything needs to be pulled out and removed. I'd love to hear an unbiased opinion (not emotional from me, and financially motivated from a pro).

Thank you!

Comment: Asking how to do something fits SE's goals better than asking if you should do something. And in this case it's a judgement call; for many, soap and water (maybe with a bit of bleach), vacuuming, and replacing/installing shelf linings would be more than adequate while others would go the bleach-everything-to-death route.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a subjective question, as every person has a different tolerance for risk and "ickyness". Mice can carry bacteria that cause respiratory ailments, and the notion of feces in one's home is unpleasant.

Personally, I'd vaccuum all hard surfaces with a HEPA filter installed and call it a day. The bits in the attic insulation are there to stay unless you were to completely replace it, and that's a fool's errand, in my opinion. It's likely that there will be more at some point anyway, and if anyone is in the attic they should be wearing respiration protection.

Good luck.